# Calculate 2 dataGridView and Update an SQL Data Table

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have two datatables Table_1 and Table_2.
What's wrong with my code? I can't add in Table_2 the sum of the stock from Table_1?

When I update once, I have a correct output.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1632bs&s=5

When I press the update button once more, it updates only the first row, as shown in the following pic:

http://tinypic.com/r/350p6hd/5

```
private void txtid_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection csq = new SqlConnection("workstation id=;initial catalog=iridadb; integrated security=SSPI");

        SqlDataAdapter dsaq = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet dsq = new DataSet();

        dsaq.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table_1 where left(id, " + txtid.Text.Length + ") = '" + txtid.Text + "' order by ItemID ASC", csq);
        dsq.Clear();

        dsaq.Fill(dsq);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dsq.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        bindDataGridView2();
    }

    public void bindDataGridView2()
    {

        SqlConnection csq = new SqlConnection("workstation id=;initial catalog=iridadb; integrated security=SSPI");

        SqlDataAdapter dsaq = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet dsq = new DataSet();

        dsaq.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table_2 ", csq);
        dsq.Clear();

        dsaq.Fill(dsq);

        dataGridView2.DataSource = dsq.Tables[0];
        dataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

    }

    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (!dataGridView1.Rows[i].IsNewRow)
            {


                SqlConnection connan = new SqlConnection("DATA SOURCE=;initial catalog=iridadb; integrated security=SSPI");
                SqlDataAdapter danan = new SqlDataAdapter();
                danan.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE  Table_2 SET Stock  = @Stock  WHERE itemID = @itemID", connan);
                danan.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@itemID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value).ToString();

                danan.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Stock", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()) + Double.Parse(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString())).ToString();



                connan.Open();
                danan.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connan.Close();

                bindDataGridView2();


            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your calculations of sum:

```
(Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()) + Double.Parse(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString())).ToString();
```

You calculating a sum of rows with same `rowindex`, but updating database by itemID

when in looping your index `i = 2` then it count Stock(where itemID = 03) + Stock(where itemID = 02) -> as Stock of item 02 not updating it always stay on 100. thats why item 03 stock will be always as 100 + 1

Because total stock in the database already, then use query like this

```
UPDATE  Table_2 SET 
Stock = CAST(
        CAST(Stock AS DECIMAL(19,4)) + CAST(@Stock AS DECIMAL(19,4)) 
        AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
WHERE itemID = @itemID"
```

and take values from only `datagridview1`

```
danan.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@itemID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value).ToString();

// 
danan.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Stock", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString())
```

P.S. Sorry, but really seems strangely, when you stored values of `Double`/`Decimal` as `VARCHAR` ...?

Comment: i m getting error on calculate sum.

my datatable column is varchar(max).

danan.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE  Table_2 SET Stock  = Stock + @Stock  WHERE itemID = @itemID", connan);
                     danan.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@itemID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value).ToString();

                    danan.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Stock", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()));

Comment: @paminos, I updated my answer with converting `VARCHAR` to `DECIMAL` and after calculating back to `VARCHAR`

Comment: Solved.
Grazie Mille Fabio :-)